# Using pointers in GCD program but no output

Tags: c

I'm trying to calculate the gcd of two numbers using functions and I thought of using pointers. But I'm not getting an output.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int *gcdNum(int *a, int *b)
{
    int reminder;
    while (((*a) % (*b)) > 0)
    {
        reminder = (*a) % (*b);
        *a = *b;
        *b = reminder;
    }
    return &b;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int a, b;
    fprintf(stdout,"Enter two nosL: ");
    fscanf(stdin,"%i\n%i",&a, &b); 
    gcdNum(&a,&b);
    
    return 0;
}
```

The output is :

```
user@DESKTOP-f6C:/mnt/c/Users/Documents/C programs$ ./func
Enter two nosL: 12
4
```

The program terminates after this.
P.S: Currently learning C programming.

Comment: where are you printing the output

Comment: You aren't doing anything with `b` after calling `gcdNum` - are you sure the fact that the program terminates is not just because you have hit the end of `main`?

Comment: Please enable full compiler warnings, fix them all before running the program.

Comment: the gcdNum() function has a return&b which is expected to return the value to the main

Comment: `return &b` returns the address where `b` is residing on the stack, not the GCD result. Anyway how does using pointers avoid the need for multiple declarations? The function can use its arguments like local variables. Assuming your solution works: it destroys the original values of `a` and `b`.

Comment: By using pointers, in main you are loosing the initial values of `a` and `b`. Better to copy these values: `int gcdNum (int a, int b) { ... return b;}`

Comment: I don't why you claim that this code "avoids multiple variable declarations".

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things wrong with this program.

I'm not sure if you have any previous programming experience with any other language, but if you do, you should know how `return` works. Here, when you return a reference to &b, you actually need a variable to store the value in, so store the return value in a, b or a new variable like so: `<variable_name> = gcd(&a, &b);`.

Second, even if you stored the value, you... never actually do any printing after you call `gcd`. So for example, if you stored the return value in `a`, append `printf("%i\n", a);` to your program after calling `gcd`.

(Speaking of which, why are you printing to the console with `fprintf?` I'm not sure where you are learning from that you decided to use `fprintf` to do normal printing instead of `printf`)

Lastly, by using pointers to pass by reference, you are modifying the original values of `a` and `b` that were there before you called the function. You probably didn't intend for this to happen, and it could cause issues in the future.

I really don't see why you would have an issue with passing by value here; no new variables would really need to be declared, and pass-by-value is honestly better for a function like this. In order to fix this function to not change the values of `a` and `b` and still pass by reference, you would have to create two new variables which would serve as copies of the arguments, and I'm pretty sure this is the exact opposite of what you are trying to do.

Comment: printf("GCD is %i", *b);
    return b;                     Adding this to the function fixed the issue

Comment: Alright, good for you. However, your `return b` still literally does nothing in this code, and it is better to put the print outside the function (it'd mean that every time you use `gcd` the answer would print, even when you just want to simply calculate `gcd` and not print that line). You definitely need to learn what return is, probably how to use variables properly, and definitely what pass-by-reference actually is. You may think your problem fixed, but it is _definitely_ not.

Answer (score -1):

I got a fix to the issue. The modified code is:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int *gcdNum(int *a, int *b)
{
    int reminder;
    while (((*a) % (*b)) > 0)
    {
        reminder = (*a) % (*b);
        *a = *b;
        *b = reminder;
    }
    printf("GCD is %i", *b);
    return b;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int a, b;
    fprintf(stdout,"Enter two nosL: ");
    fscanf(stdin,"%i\n%i",&a, &b);
    gcdNum(&a,&b);
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
user@DESKTOP-KI53T6C:/mnt/c/Users/user/Documents/C programs$ gcc funcCh.c -o func -Wall -pedantic -std=c99
user@DESKTOP-KI53T6C:/mnt/c/Users/user/Documents/C programs$ ./func
Enter two nosL: 12
4
GCD is 4
```

Comment: As already specified, you return b which is a pointer and also you do not use it. Mainly the value contained in b (in main) is the result of cdgNum. In your case gcdNum could be a void function.